# How to get value inside foreach to set to the parent Array?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to get value inside foreach to set to parent array properly? when i trying to get the value, it said, the return type is void, so it cannot be set, here is my code :

Here is my partner.java Model :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "msPartner")
public class Partner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String partnerCode;

    public String partnerName;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<PartnerShipment> partnerShipment;
    
}
```

and then here is my PartnerShipment.java :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "msPartnerShipment")
public class PartnerShipment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String partnerShipmentCode;

    public String partnerShipmentAddress;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "partnerId")
    // @NotAudited
    // @JsonManagedReference
    public Partner partner;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;
    
}
```

and here is i my service, i want to update two row of my partner_shipment table :

```
public Partner edit(InputRequest<Partner> request) {
    Partner partner;
    String currentUser = request.getLoggedInUser();

    Long partnerId = request.getPartner().getId();

    Partner oldPartner = partnerRepository.findById(partnerId).get();
    if (oldPartner != null) {
        partner = request.getPartner();
        partner.setCreateDate(oldPartner.getCreateDate());
        partner.setCreatedBy(oldPartner.getCreatedBy());
        partner.setModifiedBy(currentUser);
        
        partner.getPartnerShipment().forEach(d -> {
            d.setId(oldPartner.getPartnerShipment().forEach(a -> a.getId()));
            d.setPartner(partner);
            d.setCreateDate(oldPartner.getPartnerShipment().get(0).getCreateDate());
            d.setCreatedBy(oldPartner.getCreatedBy());
            d.setModifiedBy(currentUser);
        });

        return partnerRepository.save(partner);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Employee not found with id : " + partnerId);
    }
    
}
```

here in this line

```
d.setId(oldPartner.getPartnerShipment().forEach(a -> a.getId()));
```

here is the complete error :

```
The method setId(Long) in the type PartnerShipment is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

how can i get the old id from each row of partner_shipment and set it to the partner_shipment, so hibernate will update the row based on new value properly?

Comment: do you want to do `d.setId(oldPartner.getId);`

Comment: no, i want to setId based on each old PartnerShipment id, so the hibernate will update each row as the value change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this doesn't work:

```
 d.setId(oldPartner.getPartnerShipment().forEach(a -> a.getId()));
```

The reason it won't work is that `forEach` doesn't return anything.  The expression

```
 oldPartner.getPartnerShipment().forEach(a -> a.getId())
```

says to call `getId()` on *every* partner shipment of `oldPartner` and throw them all away!  So there is no value to pass to `setId`.

So the question is, which of the (many) shipment ids in the `oldPartner` shipment list do you want to set `d`'s id to?

- The smallest one?  The largest one?  The first one?  The last one?
- The *corresponding* one?  If so ... how do you work out which shipment in `oldPartner` corresponds to a given shipment in `partner`?

If the correspondence is positional (i.e. `oldShipments[i]` corresponds to `newShipments[i]`) then you would be better off using a loop; e.g. something like this:

```
    List<PartnerShipment> oldShipments = oldPartner.getPartnerShipment();
    List<PartnerShipment> shipments = partner.getPartnerShipment();
    Date shipmentCreateDate = oldShipments.get(0).getCreateDate();

    for (int i = 0; i < oldShipments.size(); i++) :
        PartnerShipment d = shipments.get(i);
        d.setId(oldShipments.get(i).getId());
        d.setPartner(partner);
        d.setCreateDate(shipmentCreateDate);
        d.setCreatedBy(oldPartner.getCreatedBy());
        d.setModifiedBy(currentUser);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you stephen, i just realize that's the limitation of forEach lambda expression, thank u very much

Comment: The other problem is that `foreach` doesn't correctly express what you were actually trying to do.